# Abstract contents of gitlab-ci file to only use "include"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I've a gitlab-ci file that works as is no problem, however, a question has been asked as to whether we can abstract the contents of this file/move this file to another repo and reference the file instead, and once called upon all stages within the file will run.

```
gitlab-ci.yml file

stages:
  - deployment

test:
  stage: deployment
  trigger:
     include: /reference/to/file.yml
```

The error I'm receiving is "No stages/jobs for this pipeline" - any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full URL to the location of the file:

```
test:
  stage: deployment
  trigger:
    include:
      remote: 'https://gitlab.com/awesome-project/raw/main/.before-script-template.yml'
```

See the docs on [CI/CD Include Examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html), [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includeremote), and [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger).